# Coloring subset of lines in a plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors

I am trying to connect the dots on my plot using geom_path(). I also want to color certain lines(intervals) based on a group variable(t). This is what I have so far:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=x)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path(color=t)
```

What this does is it "incorrectly" connects the points based on this group. I just want the correct connecting lines to have a separate color.

Could any one help me with this?

Comment: Please provide a sample of `data`, such as via `head`.  But generally, you'll need some sort of factor to pass to `ggplot` to get different parameters to show up in different colors; eg, via `ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = factor(octopus)))`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I want to color certain lines... based on a group variable" but not "connecting the points based on this group." Perhaps you could share a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not share your data: You could be experiencing an edge case that occurs if you color by boolean; e.g., a specific value of a variable.

In this case, ggplot groups your `geom_path` by `var == x`. You can prevent this by adding `group = 1`.

#### Basic (somewhat contrived) example

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
    geom_point(aes(mpg, hp)) +
    geom_path(aes(mpg, hp))
```

[image: 1]

#### Above plot with `color = cyl == 4`

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
    geom_point(aes(mpg, hp)) +
    geom_path(aes(mpg, hp, color = cyl == 4))
```

[image: 3]

#### Above plot with `group = 1`

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
    geom_point(aes(mpg, hp)) +
    geom_path(aes(mpg, hp, color = cyl == 4, group = 1))
```

[image: 2]

Comment: Thank you! Worked beautifully with "group=1"

Comment: Great! For the future: You will get faster and more precise answers to your question if you share your data via, e.g., `dput(head(df, 20))`!

Answer (score 1):

If you pass either a single color (not what you want), or a vector of colors equal to the number of plot elements, you can get ggplot to color the lines for you. So, for instance,

```
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=x)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path(color=rainbow(10))
```

[image: A plot with intervals colored]